# Register-Scheduledjob creates a job but it never runs at startup

Tags: powershell, azure-rm-template

I have tried 100 ways to register-scheduledjob to run a script that would start the program.
nothing seems to be working consistently.
my last attempt was using Register-ScheduledTask, this one does **create the job** but **doesn't start it automatically** at system startup. **the funny thing is if I run it manually once**, it would start on its own on future restarts. but if I wanted to run it once myself there is no point in scheduling the job!

this is what I am doing:

```
$description = "Scheduling job using Tasks" 
$taskPath = "\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\" 
$argument = "'Register-ScheduledJob -Name "+$scheduledJobName+" -Trigger "+$trigger+" -FilePath "+$TaskParametersPath+" -ScheduledJobOption "+$option+" -Credential "+$cred+" -RunAs32 2>&1'" 

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument $argument 
$taskTriger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup -RandomDelay 00:00:30
$job = Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $taskTriger -TaskName $scheduledJobName -Description $description -TaskPath $taskPath
```

the original code I had was:

```
$job = Register-ScheduledJob -Name $scheduledJobName -Trigger $trigger -FilePath $TaskParametersPath -ScheduledJobOption $option -Credential $cred -RunAs32 2>&1
```

I also tried this one:

```
$job = Register-ScheduledJob -Name $scheduledJobName -Trigger $trigger -FilePath $TaskParametersPath -ScheduledJobOption $option -Credential $cred -Authentication Credssp 2>&1
```

with trigger and option:

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup -RandomDelay 00:00:30

$option = New-ScheduledJobOption -RunElevated
```

$taskParametersPath is a powershell script that starts another powershell script and passes all the required parameters for it.
all of this works occasionally, but sometimes it fails to schedule the job with the error I have here. it works all the time when I am logged into the machine and try to register the job, but it fails occasionally when I run it as a part of VM creation script using azure stack templates. :(
this is the error I get:

```
ERROR : FullyQualifiedErrorId :     CantRegisterScheduledJobDefinition,Microsoft.PowerShell.ScheduledJob.RegisterScheduledJobCommand
2018/06/01 23:41:47 : ERROR : Exception:Microsoft.PowerShell.ScheduledJob.ScheduledJobException: An error occurred while registering scheduled job definition VaaSRestartTask to the Windows Task Scheduler.  The Task Scheduler error is: The user name or password is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007052E). ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The user name or password is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007052E)
  at TaskScheduler.ITaskFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(String Path, ITaskDefinition pDefinition, Int32 flags, Object UserId, Object password, _TASK_LOGON_TYPE LogonType, Object sddl)
  at Microsoft.PowerShell.ScheduledJob.ScheduledJobWTS.CreateTask(ScheduledJobDefinition definition)
  at Microsoft.PowerShell.ScheduledJob.ScheduledJobDefinition.AddToWTS()
  at Microsoft.PowerShell.ScheduledJob.ScheduledJobDefinition.Register()
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.PowerShell.ScheduledJob.ScheduledJobDefinition.Register()
  at    Microsoft.PowerShell.ScheduledJob.RegisterScheduledJobCommand.ProcessRecord()
2018/06/01 23:41:47 : ERROR : Category:InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power...edJobDefinition:ScheduledJobDefinition) [Register-ScheduledJob], ScheduledJobException
```

Comment: Hi Nadia, this code looks like your attempt to register a scheduled task (which itself registers a scheduled job). Could you show us the original code you tried, that created a scheduled job? If you could please also explain what you are trying in the scheduled job exactly (it's typically a PowerShell script), and what the meaning of the `+` signs are in your strings (I don't know why you're doing `"+$scheduledJobName+"` for example).

Comment: Hi Brian, just added more details regarding the issue. the + signs are for adding parameters to the string.

Comment: Thanks I see now (wonky SO code formatting threw me off); I think that you can avoid the string concatenation since the string is double quoted, so instead of doing `$var = "'thing " + $otherthing + " thirdthing'"` you can do `$var = "'thing $otherthing thirdthing'"`. But that isn't itself a problem just a suggestion. As for your tasks, maybe you checked this already, but if you're creating a task that runs on system startup, it will not run until you restart the machine. Does the script that creates the job actually perform a restart too?